# How can I show a modal window once per user session?

Tags: jquery, session, window, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a `script`, to display a modal window on page load when entering my website (whichever page) but only once during the same browsing `session`, so when the user closes and reopens the `browser` he sees the modal window again in my website. Can somebody help me?

I found a reply to this question with a `jquery` plugin link that does not work now and a piece of code i am not sure how to use. Please see below for the reply given to another similar question

The link given is http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

and the code given is

```
if ($.cookie('modal') != 'shown')    {
      $.cookie('modal', 'shown');
      // code to show modal    
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: your provided `jquery` cookie plugin link is not working, i think you try to point us to this link http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you saying.

Comment: your provided link i.e.http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt direct me to a non-working page i.e.`Page Not Found`

Comment: have you placed your plugin file correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new plugin location is [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Once you include the [script](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) then your code should work as-is.

As for showing a modal dialog, the simplest way is with an `alert()` call. There are also several [plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/) you can take a look at that offer a more polished look.

**UPDATE**

Example added [here](http://jsbin.com/ogadil/1/). It will only show the alert dialog the first time you visit unless you clear cookies. Click edit to see source code.

Comment: Yep, just include it as a script tag _after_ the jQuery script tag.

Comment: ok Great. I will try it out and let you know what happens. Thanks a lot

Comment: Included the script but nothing seems to happen. I refresh the page and the modal box still appears.I want it to appear only once per session until the window is closed. Any changes to be made in the code?

Comment: I added an example, it's pretty much what you had above and works for me. Take a look at the source and see what you are doing differently.

Comment: do you have a link to the example please? oh sorry found the link

Comment: The code i'm using is below . still does not work. when i refresh the page the box shows up. for ur page it works                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: ok this finally works but only with an alert message box. if i add the modal code, does not work.please see the code im adding if ($.cookie('modal') != 'shown')    {
      $.cookie('modal', 'shown');
      $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 750,
            width:1045,
            modal: true,resizable:false,draggable:false
        });
  
}

Comment: You should probably create a new question which is confined only to the modal dialog display (leave out the cookie stuff) and you'll get plenty of help with it. Go ahead and also leave a link here.